# Why is this approach to print the frequency of each character of a given string not working?

Tags: python, string, list, loops, for-loop

[why does the iteration variable **a** skips the character value 'a' in list and directly moves over to 'd' from 'r'?](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4zhdN.png)

Comment: Do not post screenshots of code. Post the code itself here so people can help.

Comment: Hi Tanay! After you copy/paste your code from your screenshot into your question, can you consider accepting one of the answers?

Answer (score 0):

Because you have a remove operation while traversing `lst` in a for loop, the elements in `lst` are decreasing.

Based on the existing code, you can try to modify `for a in lst` to `for a in lst.copy()`

Answer (score 0):

Because after first iteration "a" position is 0 and it take 1st position item i.e "d".

```py
st=input("Input String")
st=list(st)
op=dict(Counter(st))
```